# How to change scatter XY plot color dependent from string Z value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I would like that make scatter plot with different dots colors, dependent from column `'Value'`. For example all `"rand"` dots would be blue and `"qmax"` red. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'State': [1000, 1002, 1001, 1003, 1000, 1003, 1001],
    'Score': [62, 47, 55, 74, 31, 50, 60],
    'Value': ['rand','qmax','rand','qmax','rand','qmax','qmax']
}, columns=['State', 'Score', 'Value'])

# Create figure with plot
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.scatter(df['State'], df['Score'])
plt.show()
```

My dataframe:

```
    State  Score Value
0   1000     62  rand
1   1002     47  qmax
2   1001     55  rand
3   1003     74  qmax
4   1000     31  rand
5   1003     50  qmax
6   1001     60  qmax
```

Scatter plot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the values in the `'Value'` column and, in each iteration, filter the dataframe and plot the filtered data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'State': [1000, 1002, 1001, 1003, 1000, 1003, 1001],
    'Score': [62, 47, 55, 74, 31, 50, 60],
    'Value': ['rand','qmax','rand','qmax','rand','qmax','qmax']
}, columns=['State', 'Score', 'Value'])

print(df)

# Create figure with plot
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

for value in df['Value'].unique():
    ax1.scatter(df[df['Value'] == value]['State'], df[df['Value'] == value]['Score'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you want to choose the color for each individual value in `'Value'`, you can define a dictionary as this one:

```
colors = {'rand': 'blue', 'qmax': 'red'}
```

And specify the `color` parameter in the `scatter` call:

```
for value in df['Value'].unique():
    ax1.scatter(df[df['Value'] == value]['State'], df[df['Value'] == value]['Score'], color = colors[value])
```

[image]

---

You could also show a legend:

```
for value in df['Value'].unique():
    ax1.scatter(df[df['Value'] == value]['State'], df[df['Value'] == value]['Score'], color = colors[value], label = value)
```

[image]